# r error on replacing a character on a string

Tags: r

I'm reading a file that has a structure like this:

```
[1111111]aaaa;bbbb;cccc
[2222222]dddd;ffff;gggg
```

And i want to have a data frame like this:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
1111111    aaaa       bbbb      cccc
2222222    dddd       ffff      gggg
```

So i need to split by ; and replace all the [ ]

So here is my code :

Read file

```
df<-read.csv("file.csv",sep=";")
```

Replace the [ ]

```
df_V1 <- gsub(pattern="[",replacement="",df$V1)  #ERROR HERE!
df_V1 <- gsub(pattern="]",replacement=";",df$V1) #Replace the ] to ;
```

Then merge all together

```
df_V1 <- do.call(rbind.data.frame,strsplit(df_V1,split=";"))
Data<- cbind(
                df_V1,
                df[,c(2:ncol(df))])
```

And here is my output

```
View(Data)

 Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D
 [1111111    aaaa       bbbb      cccc
 [2222222    dddd       ffff      gggg
```

And dont know why the first [ cant be replaced, i already tried use gsub and delete the first character of the string, but nothing seems to solve it. Any idea?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can read the data using `readLines` first, do the string changes with `gsub` and then read with `read.csv`

```
read.csv(text=sub(";", "", gsub("[][]", ";", lines)), 
   sep=";", header=FALSE, col.names = paste0("Column", LETTERS[1:4]), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
#1 1111111    aaaa    bbbb    cccc
#2 2222222    dddd    ffff    gggg
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file1.txt")
```

Comment: Thank you, you solded my problem! :) thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

If the columns truly are fixed in length, then read_fwf in library readr is useful.

```
library(readr)
read_fwf(
"[1111111]aaaa;bbbb;cccc
[2222222]dddd;ffff;gggg
", fwf_cols("Column A"=c(2,8), "Column B"=c(10,13), "Column C"=c(15,18), "column D"=c(20,23)))

#    `Column A` `Column B` `column C` `Column D`
#        <int>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
# 1    1111111       aaaa       bbbb       cccc
# 2    2222222       dddd       ffff       gggg
```